# How can I serve images from a subdirectory path (/public) at the root path (/) with webpack server?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, webpack-4, webpack-style-loader

I am developing components with [Playroom](https://github.com/seek-oss/playroom) for use in a Next.js application. Right now, I am trying to figure out how to configure Webpack to resolve the following inconsistency:

1. I use Next.js for my application, so  I need to write `<img src="/image.jpeg">` and `background-image: url("/image.jpeg")` to display an image stored at `public/image.jpeg` relative to the project root. ([reference to docs on this](https://nextjs.org/docs#static-file-serving-eg-images))
2. However, Playroom appears to resolve `<img>` `src` paths and `background-image: url(...)` paths from the root of the project. I need to use either `<img src="public/image.jpeg"/>` or `background-image: url('public/image.jpeg')` to display the image stored at `public/image.jpeg`
3. This makes the paths for my images in the Playroom environment incompatible with the paths that images need to resolve properly in the Next.js environment.

Ideally, I would like all image paths starting with `/` to resolve to paths starting with `/public` in the Playroom environment. For example, `/image.jpeg` would resolve to `/public/image.jpeg`

Playroom exposes an option for providing custom webpack config. How can I use this config to accomplish the above behavior, and resolve this issue?